# Find Non Duplicate Values in Two Tables

Tags: php, sql

I want to create a procedure that checks the data in 'Table1' against the data in 'Table2'. I have used this query to perform the procedure.

```
$sq_query = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.name = Table2.name)';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sq_query);
if (!$result) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

BTW, I want to find out any `name` which isn't in 'Table2' but is in 'Table1'. I have been unsuccessful in locating missing files so far.

Comment: Your Select is valid SQL and does exacly what you want.

Comment: What is your question?  Your method is probably the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using left join

```
SELECT * FROM table1 left join 
Table2 on Table1.name = Table2.name
where Table2.name is null
```

Comment: it doesn't return any values but executed without any error. However, there are lots of non-duplicate values in Table2

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format @Strange

Comment: BTW I have executed the same query in my `PHPMYADMIN` and it returned the desired data. Thanks a lot.